# C# .NET how to connect to oracle 11g database if only given httprequest header information

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g, network-programming

Alright I know there are bunch of ways to connect to a oracle 11g database. And I have seen lots of tutorials on this topic. My problem is that I'm not the one that host the server, it's unlikely to get the SID of the server and the database name from the people that hosted it. I only know the server IP address and ports and I'm able to send and receive Httprequests to or from the server using my username and password.

Is there a possible way to get the information I needed for the connection string?

My goal is to use odp.net. The only two things I need is the SID and SERVER below. Anyone can help?

```
    Oracle.RACE =
(DESCRIPTION=
   (ADDRESS_LIST=
     (ADDRESS=
       (PROTOCOL=TCP)
       (HOST=127.0.0.1)
       (PORT=1521)
     )
   )
   (CONNECT_DATA=
     (SID=RACE)
     (SERVER=DEDICATED)
   )
)
```

Comment: `it's unlikely to get the SID of the server and the database name from the people that hosted it` Then it is also unlikely that the database is configured so that you can access it.

Comment: @EricJ. I can access it via an application frontend, I know if I can access it via connection string once I have the information :)